Getting Error: unable to determine transport target for "pino-datadog-transport" in Next js standalone mode
I'm trying to run Nextjs app using output:'standalone' mode but getting:
Error: unable to determine transport target for "pino-datadog-transport"
    at fixTarget (/app/node_modules/pino/lib/transport.js:144:13)
    at Function.transport (/app/node_modules/pino/lib/transport.js:114:22)
    at h.init (/app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:180966)
    at new h (/app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:180803)
    at h.getInstance (/app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:180915)
    at f.updateSessionConfig (/app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:183627)
    at new f (/app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:183836)
    at f.getInstance (/app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:183964)
    at /app/.next/server/chunks/4010.js:1:66204

However, this works fine in default mode.
It works if I import the entire package like import 'pino-datadog-transport' but first js build size becomes very heavy, slowing down the app overall.
Note: The app is deployed in the dockerized container.
